# visual studio 2012 syntax error with /<%: method %>/;

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a line of code getting a regex from c# code In a

```
 $("#but").keyup(function () 
 {

     var regex = /<%:StringKeeper.InfoRegex.ToString()%>/;
     var info = $("#Info").val(); // info from edit-field
     var matches = regex.exec(info);

     var part1 = matches[1];
     var part2 = matches[2];

          if (matches != null)
              {
                 if (part1.length != 6 && part2.length != 5 || 
                    (part1 == '000000' || part2 == '00000'))
                     {
                        showWarning = true;
                     }
              }
           else  { showWarning = true; }

 if (showWarning) 
 {
 $("#butWarning").show();
 $("#submitButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 });

$("#but").keyup();
```

The issue is that visual studio doesn't realize that the ";" at the end of the first line isn't commented.
It therefore gives warnings on the next line of code even though the code still works.

EDIT: The code now shows full function as people wanted more information. Basically if on key up event of some input field the regex is checked to see if the input matches my regex if not im going to throw up a warning.

```
        public static Regex InfoRegex
    {
        get
        {
            return new Regex(@"^[Xx][Yy]0(\d{6})(\d{5})$");
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to work around this or what the new syntax is that I'm suppose to be using?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Get the Regex object from the static c# class and use it!

Comment: What is the actual output in the browser for this value?

Comment: @SatanEnglish I'm unfamiliar with this `/<% ... %>/` syntax. I really have no idea what that is, but if you're just trying to grab an object from your static class, you just need `var regex = StringKeeper.OfficialID.ToString();`

Comment: Na that doesn't work just checked it when I do that my regex check doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense cannot handle all possible combinations of .js and C# and HTML. I notice this from time to time, and then I wonder how they made it work at all.

Your code would actually generate a JS comment IF InfoRegex was string.Empty:

```
 var regex = /<%:StringKeeper.InfoRegex.ToString()%>/;
```

(This reminds me of the C puzzle

```
int *p, *q;
int a = *p/*q;
```

)

Change your original line to

```
 var regex = /<%:StringKeeper.InfoRegex.ToString()%>/; /*
             /dummy-expression-for-IDE/;   /*           */
```

In IDE mode, the computed RegEx is regarded as comment, so the multi-line begin-comment is ignored. The second begin-comment is needed for the end-comment of case 2:

In compile mode, the computed RegEx is used, and the multi-line comment starts in line 1.

Comment: Nice this works shame that I have to put so much in to fix it

Answer (score 1):

try this, however you should try in aspx or ascx file, not js file.

`var regex = /<%=StringKeeper.InfoRegex.ToString()%>/;`